# django form action url 'abc' is redirect to abc twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In django *index.html*, I have below code

```
<form class="selectedPizza" action="{% url 'cost' %}" method="POST">
<!--Do some action here-->
<form>
```

In my app(order) *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("cost/", views.cost, name="cost")
]
```

In main site(pizza) *urls.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("orders.urls")),
    path("cost/", include("orders.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

In *views.py*

```
def index(request):
    #some action here
    return render(request, 'orders/index.html', context)

def cost(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
       #some action here
        return render(request, 'orders/cost.html', context)
```

After submitting the form I am redirected to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cost/cost/".
I am learning Django and not able to find a possible way to get this form to redirect to cost.html page after submitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have included "orders.urls" twice in your main urls. Remove the second one. "cost" is part of the included URL, you don't need it in the main one as well.